# .net core 2.2 and wide open CORS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, cors

Since .net core 2.2, we can't accept all origins and accept credentials at the same time. While it solves a security, there are cases where we don't care and want things wide open.

So, the proposed solution I found on several threads is:

```
    Services.AddCors(CorsOptions =>
    {
        CorsOptions.AddPolicy("AllowAll", P => { P
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
        });
    });
```

but this still gives the following error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What would be a working solution for a wide open CORS with 2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need is the following as @Praneet mentioned. Create an all-access policy

```
services
    .AddCors(options => options
        .AddPolicy("WideOpen", p => p
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader())
    );
```

You would also need a line in `Configure` method to enable it globally

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("WideOpen");
}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
services
    .AddCors(options => options
        .AddPolicy("WideOpen", p => p
            .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
            .WithOrigins("*")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials())
    );
```

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#set-the-allowed-origins) `SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains` is required for the allowed origins. So I have set `WithOrigins` to use wildcards

**UPDATED ANSWER 2**

ok, I got an idea for your problem. I don't think that it's an ideal or recommended solution, but it will work. You can have a middleware, that injects the Response headers for each request which are required to allow AnyOrigin, AnyMethod and AnyHeader along with the credentials. However, it will only add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for the Origin that is present in the request, hence allowing any origin.

If Ajax check doesn't work, you can remove it. The only downside is, that it will inject the headers for all requests.

```
public class WideOpenCorsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public WideOpenCorsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var response = context.Response;

        // check if it's an ajax request
        if (context.Request.Headers != null && context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                new[] { (string)context.Request.Headers["Origin"] });
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                new[] { "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" });
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] { "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" });
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new[] { "true" });
            response.StatusCode = 200;
        }

        // if not a pre-flight request
        if (context.Request.Method != "OPTIONS")
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also have this Extension method, so you can easily use it in the `Configure` method.

```
// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class MiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseWideOpenCors(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<WideOpenCorsMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Finally, in the `Configure` method, add the following line, probably at the top:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseWideOpenCors();
}
```

Comment: that will work, but without AllowCredentials, so no cookies allowed. Since .net core 2.2, AllowAnyOrigin and AllowCredentials are NOT allowed together anymore; so either you need to list the origins or you can't receive the cookies. Until .net core 2.1, it was fine. What I need is to find how to make the 2.1 behavior under 2.2

Comment: ok, I haven't tested it myself, but see if the updated answer works for you

Comment: That's the old 2.1 method that doesn't work anymore in 2.2

Comment: seems like you are out of luck. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3106) and [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/pull/7751)

Comment: Perhaps, you would need to read the origins from somewhere, but that means you would need to add them somewhere, in some database as well. One option is to use middleware that will inspect the request and will add it as an allowed origin to the CORS policy. The policy will get updated at runtime. Please have a look at this [post](https://www.tpeczek.com/2017/04/reconfiguring-cors-policy-in-aspnet.html). Although in this post, the policy is updated using origins controller. However, you can use a similar approach and inject the `ICorsPolicyAccessor` in the middleware. I hope that helps

Comment: However, one drawback of this approach is that if you have thousands of clients and literally every client, it will hog your memory.

Comment: yes, I thought about that but since it's an open service, the list can be quite large over time. Although it could be managed on the fly by removing old clients, it's not ideal

Comment: @Thomas Please have a look at the UPDATED ANSWER 2. As I mentioned, it's not ideal or recommended, but I think it will work. Please make sure you remove/comment the `AddCors` and `UseCors` lines. This middleware will inject the required headers which are required for CORS. You can modify the logic slightly to compare the origin, and only inject the headers if it's not your domain. I have added a condition to check if it's an Ajax request then inject the headers otherwise continue. The ajax condition may or may not work depends on how the call is made i.e. via developer console, Postman etc.

Comment: It didn't work: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https:xxx' from origin 'https:yyy' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: I have another idea, I would like to try. Do you mind sharing the code that sends the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: I don't have the request because it's the front end guys that did the test; I just asked and was told: you need to allow this header: authorization

Comment: In that case, you can probably try adding the header to `response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                new[] { "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" });` and see if that works.

Comment: `authorization` header? You mentioned that this needs to be allowed, but that's not part of my solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192441/discussion-between-thomas-and-shahzad-hassan).

Answer (score 0):

In your appsettings.json add your cors origins. Something like this:

```
"CorsOrigins": {
    "Urls": [ "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:8090", "https://localhost:44376" ]
  }
```

Then set your startup like this:

```
var corsOriginsSection = Configuration.GetSection("CorsOrigins");
var origins = corsOriginsSection.Get<CorsOrigins>();

services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", p => p.WithOrigins(origins.Urls)
                                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                                               .AllowAnyHeader()));
```

Then on your controller add this :

```
 [EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
```

That should work.

The class that I would use is this:

```
public interface ICorsOrigins
{
    string[] Urls { get; set; }
}
public class CorsOrigins : ICorsOrigins
{
    public string[] Urls { get; set; }
}
```

I would keep the origins in appsettings, cause otherwise it will be hard-coded thing.

just like specific origin, create a policy All Access and use it as per your requirement

Comment: That's specifically what I want to avoid: I want to have CORS wide open: any client, any method, any header, all cookies, no checks, no security, allow everything and everyone :) I can't make a list of clients since we don't know them

Comment: That's why I said just like specific origin, create a policy All Access and use it as per your requirement

Why dont you try for Identity Server.

Comment: But in that policy, you need to set the origins? I don't need identity server, we're using a JWT to allow access with short term throwaway accounts, so the accounts have absolutely no value and can be hacked by whoever feels like wasting time. But since we go through a browser, we need cookies to go through (for the JWT) and allow any origin (since we don't know the origin prior to the call)